# Jmeter execution fails while running Junit Test jar for multiple user

Tags: junit, jmeter

I am trying to execute a Junit Jar in Jmeter. In the Script, chrome browser is launched and login screen of my website is displayed, where Username and Password is entered and login button is clicked. So when 2 user load is applied, 2 chrome browsers are launched which is as per the script. However, the credentials which is suppose to get enter in the 2nd Browser are **overwriting** the credentials field of the 1st Browser. So script for 2nd Browser is failing as nothing is getting entered in the login screen.

The scripts run successfully on Eclipse.

**Headless browser**. I have added the headless browser code in the script. Now the browser aren't getting launched, everything is running in the background, this should have solved the issue. But the issue still persists when putting the load of 2 users.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is with your code, i.e. according to [WebDriver FAQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe)

> WebDriver is not thread-safe. Having said that, if you can serialise access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. You /can/ on the other hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.

So I would recommend either double-checking your Java code which is being used and ensure that there are no [static](https://javapapers.com/core-java/explain-the-java-static-modifier/) functions or fields and WebDriver instances are put into [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

An easier solution would be going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) which is compatible with JMeter thread model therefore there should be no [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

You can install the WebDriver Sampler using the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)